# Java Printing: How do i go about it?

Tags: java, printing

I'm new to `Graphics` and `Graphics2D` in Java.
Now i have a project where i have to print an Invoice to an A4 sized sheet.

I've been reading [Sun's tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html) on printing.

I realized I'll need to first render the bill on a JFrame so i know what it'll look like.

Now, how do i go about setting the right sizes?
I mean - if i design the bill on a `JFrame (595, 842)` - how will i map the coordinates (of all the shapes) correctly on to the print?

I'm basically clueless about where to begin. A lil' direction please?

Thanks. : )

Comment: You have to look at reports tool.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794382/how-to-print-strings-with-line-breaks-in-java

Answer (score 1):

If you put your invoice together using a `JPanel` (better than a `JFrame`, if you don't want the title bar, etc), you can implement `Printable`, and in its `print` method, you can use the `Graphics` object passed in to render your invoice.  The `Graphics` object that the `PrintJob` passes in to the `Printable` can be used in your panel's `paint` method, but instead of it painting to the screen, it is painting to the printer.  You will probably want to temporarily turn off double buffering.

With regard to how to design the invoice, you will want to pick out a [`LayoutManager`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for your `JPanel` and add a bunch of `JLabel`s or you could use a `JList` with a custom renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article...

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt.print/print-the-text-file-and-print-preview-them.html

I hope this will help you .. :)

Regards,