# Railo Java Printing

Tags: java, printing, coldfusion, railo

I'm trying to get a program to print labels to a print attached (USB) to the server. I've been able to print to it from a batch file but for some reason the print command fails inside of coldfusion execute command. My current solution is to access the printer through Java. My problem with this solution is that I can't call any of them java methods.

The solution is based off of this answer [How to print strings with line breaks in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794382/how-to-print-strings-with-line-breaks-in-java)

The following section of code appears to work fine.

```
var printService = createObject("java","javax.print.PrintService");
var printServiceLookup = createObject("java","javax.print.PrintServiceLookup");
var docFlavor = createObject("java","javax.print.DocFlavor");   
writeDump( printService.init() );
writeOutput('<hr>');
writeDump( printServiceLookup );
writeOutput('<hr>');
writeDump( docFlavor );
```

The problem comes when I try to do a execute any of the methods that exist in the objects that were just created.

When I try to execute

```
writeDump( DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN );
```

I get:

```
Application Execution Exception
Error Type: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException : 0
Error Messages: No matching Constructor for javax.print.DocFlavor() found
```

Remember I'm trying to send a set of ZPL print commands to a printer attached to the computer. If been able to successfully do this through sockets but also need to be able to do it through a locally connected printer. So alternate solutions are acceptable provided they work with Railo & Windows.

**Updated: 4/3/2013**

```
var printer = javacast("null","");
var printers = printServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices( javacast("null",""), javacast("null","") );
for( var i=1; i le ArrayLen( printers ); i++ ) {
    if( printers[i].getName() eq printername ) {
        printer = printers[i];
        break;
    }
}

if( i gt ArrayLen( printer ) ) {
    throw('Printer #printername# was not found');
}

var Job = printer.createPrintJob();
var LabelCmdbytes = javaCast( "byte[]", javaCast( "String", LabelCmd ).getBytes() );
var Labeldoc = Doc.init( LabelCmdbytes, printer.getSupportedDocFlavors()[1].AUTOSENSE, javacast("null","" ) );
Job.print( Labeldoc, javacast("null","")
```

This solution works but I don't think that printer.getSupportedDocFlavors()[1].AUTOSENSE is the best solution to the DocFlavor value.
The environment is Windows 7 with Railo 4.1.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually [`DocFlavor.STRING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.STRING.html) is a nested class. So you need to use `$` to grab a reference to it:

```
StringFlavor = createObject("java","javax.print.DocFlavor$STRING");
```

Then you can access the public field:

```
writeDump( StringFlavor.TEXT_PLAIN );
```

---

Side note, `printService.init()` should not work. [PrintService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/PrintService.html) is an interface and cannot be instantiated. So calling `init()` should throw an error.

Comment: That makes sense and the $string solved that problem. I ended up using printServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices( javacast("null",""), javacast("null","") ); to get a list of all of the printers. I'm still not able to get the print job to come through though.

Comment: What is happening instead - error? Can you [append your new code](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22823438/edit) and any error messages?

Comment: *I don't think that printer.getSupportedDocFlavors()[1].AUTOSENSE is the best solution...* I am not familiar with `AUTOSENSE`, so unfortunately I do not have any advice to offer there.